# Is it possible to navigate a site by clicking links and then downloading the correct piece?

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

I'll try to explain what exactly I mean. I'm working on a program and I'm trying to download a bunch of images automatically from [this](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_champions) site.

Namely, I want to download the big square icons from the page you get when you click on a hero name there, for example on the [Darius](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Darius) page the image in the top left with the name `DariusSquare.png` and save that into a folder.

Is this possible or am I asking too much from C#?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, everything is possible given enough time and money. In your case, you need very little of former and none of latter :)

What you need to do can be described in following high-level steps:

- Get all `<a>` tags within the table with heroes.
- Use `WebClient` class to navigate to URL these `<a>` tags point to (i.e. to value of `href` attributes) and download the HTML
- You will need to find some wrapper element that is present on each page with hero and that contains his image. Then, you should be able to get to the image `src` attribute and download it. Alternatively, perhaps each image has an common ID you can use?

I don't think anyone will provide you with an exact code that will perform these steps for you. Instead, you need to do some research of your own.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, do a C# Web request and use the C# HTML Agility Pack to find the image url.

The you can use another web request to download the image:

Example downloading image from url:

```
public static Image LoadImage(string url)
{
    var backgroundUrl = url;
    var request = WebRequest.Create(backgroundUrl);
    var response = request.GetResponse();
    var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    return Image.FromStream(stream);
}
```

Example using html agility pack and getting some other data:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(profileurl);
request.Method = "GET";
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load(new StringReader(result));
        var root = doc.DocumentNode;
        HtmlNode profileHeader = root.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='profile-header']");
        HtmlNode profileRight = root.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='profile-right']");
        string rankHtml = profileHeader.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='best-team-1']").OuterHtml.Trim();

        #region GetPlayerAvatar
        var avatarMatch = Regex.Match(profileHeader.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/span").OuterHtml, @"(portraits[^(h3)]+).*no-repeat;", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (avatarMatch.Success)
        {
            battleNetPlayerFromDB.PlayerAvatarCss = avatarMatch.Value;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```